# question about normal subgroup and question about notation

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have two question

1)  Is normalizer of $x$ in group $G$ has same meaning as centralizer of $x$ in $G$  i.e $N(x) = C(x)$  for $x$ in $G$ , where $x$ is a element  of $G$.

2) I have read the theorem that if $G$ is group of order $p^n$ where $p$ is prime and $n>0$  then $Z(G)$ intersection $N$,  is nontrivial where $N$ is normal subgroup of $G$.  in this theorem author has used the step  $p | |N|$  i.e $p$ divides order of $N$, where $p$ is prime.  How this followed?  i.e. how can $p$ divides order of $N$?  Is if $N$ is normal subgroup of $G$ and if $p$ divides order of $G$ then $p$ divides order of $N$  ?

Comment: The normalizer is usually defined for subgroups of a group, not for elements. The centralizer can be of elements or of subgroups.Finally, by Lagrange's theorem, the order of any subgroup divides the order of the group (finite one all the time), so if the group has order a power of a prime so has *any* subgroup of that group.

Comment: Sir,  question 1) and  2) are different. 
  In 1) as you say,  usually normalizer is taken of subgroup but i have an old book of  cambridge university press in which most of time normalizer is taken of an element of G. suppose if it is ok,  then is N(x) = C(x) where x is element of G and N(x) normalzer of x in G and C(x) demotes centralizer of x in G.

Comment: Usually normalizer of $x$ is the set of all elements that commutes with $x$. How do you define centralizer of an element in $G$?

Comment: Then OK: $\;N_G(x)=C_G(x)\;$ when $\;x\in G\;$ . Both concepts coincide for a single element. As for the second question, which I understood from the beginning that it was a different one from the first, read my past comment.

Comment: thanks sir for answer of 1) .
sir in question 2)  how p divides order of N where N is normal subgroup of G and  |G| = p^n .
 please can you explain it more.

Comment: What is there to explain, Akash? Do you need it explained, that the order of a subgroup divides the order of the group? Do you need it explained that every (nontrivial) divisor of a power of a prime is a multiple of that prime?

Comment: Sir, it is true?   
 if N is normal subgroup of Group G and p divides
order of G where p is prime then is p divides
order of N ?

Comment: @Akash, it does **not** matter whether the subgroup is normal or not. Please do a favour to yourself and google "Lagrange's Theorem", understand it...and realize your question is trivial.

Comment: At last,  i want to say thank to all for clarifying me,  a very very thanks to all.

Comment: Note, Akash, that it is not enough that $p$ divide the order of $G$; but in this question we're told the order of $G$ is a power of $p$, and that's a much stronger hypothesis.